# EF4 RowCount issue on instead of insert trigger while updating an other table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, entity-framework-4, rowcount

I have some trouble with entityFramework 4. Here is the thing : 
We have a SQL server database. Every table have 3 instead of triggers for insert, update and delete. 
We know EntityFramework has some issues to deal with theses triggers, that's why we added the following code at the end of triggers to force the rowCount :

for insert :

```
DECLARE @Identifier BIGINT;
SET @Identifier = scope_identity()
SELECT @Identifier AS Identifier
```

for update/delete :

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (temp INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (1);
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

It worked fine until now : 
From an instead of insert trigger (let's say table A), I try to update a field of an other table (table B)

I know my update code perfectly work since a manual insert does the work. The issue shows up only when I'm using Entity framework.

Comment: Which `scope_identity()` is returned by the insert trigger? That's not clear from seeing this isolated code snippet. What's the last-inserted record at that moment?

Comment: You gave me the solution with your question. In my the instead of update trigger of table B, I record state history of the table by inserting in an other table.
My mistake was that the insert was not surrounded by a IF EXISTS and the insert on the third table was consuming my scope_identity() at the wrong moment.
Thank you, for your help  :)

Comment: Hehe, always tricky, these triggers. Maybe you can turn this into an answer so people will find the solution easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have the solution now, let's make a school case of this with a full example. :)**

In this example, our application is an addressBook. We want to update the business Activity (IsActive column  in Business)
everytime we add, update or delete a contact on this business. The business is considered as active if at least one of the contact
of the business is active. We record every state changements on the business in a table to have the full history.

So, we have 3 tables :

table Business (Identifier (PK Identity), Name, IsActive),
table Contact (Identifier (PK Identity), Name, IsActive, IdentifierBusiness)
table BusinessHistory (Identifier (PK Identity), IsActive, Date, IdentifierBusiness)

Here's are the triggers one we are interested in :

table Contact (trigger IoInsert):

```
-- inserting the new rows
INSERT INTO Contact
(
     Name
    ,IsActive
    ,IdentifierBusiness
)
SELECT
    t0.Name
    ,t0.IsActive
    ,t0.IdentifierBusiness
FROM
    inserted AS t0
-- Updating the business

UPDATE
    Business
SET
    IsActive = CASE WHEN 
            (
                (t0.IsActive = 1 AND Business.IsActive = 1)
                OR
                (t0.IsActive = 1 AND Business.IsActive = 0)
            ) THEN 1 ELSE 0
FROM
    inserted AS t0
WHERE
    Business.Identifier = t0.IdentifierBusiness
AND
    t0.IsActive = 1
AND
    Business.IsActive = 0   



-- Forcing rowCount for EntityFramework 
DECLARE @Identifier BIGINT;
SET @Identifier = scope_identity()
SELECT @Identifier AS Identifier
```

Table Business (trigger IoUpdate)

```
UPDATE
    Business
SET
    IsActive = 1
FROM
    Contact AS t0
WHERE
    Business.Identifier = t0.IdentifierBusiness
AND
    t0.IsActive = 1
AND
    Business.IsActive = 0   


---- Updating BusinessHistory

INSERT INTO BusinessHistory
(
    Date
    ,IsActive
    ,IdentifierBusiness
)
SELECT
    DATE()
    ,t0.IsActive
    ,t0.Identifier
FROM
    inserted AS t0
INNER JOIN
    deleted AS t1 ON t0.Identifier = t1.Identifier
WHERE   
    (t0.Identifier <> t1.Identifier)


-- Forcing rowCount for EntityFramework 
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (temp INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (1);
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Table BusinessHistory :

```
-- Updating the business

UPDATE
    Business
SET
    IsActive = CASE WHEN 
            (
                (t0.IsActive = 1 AND Business.IsActive = 1)
                OR
                (t0.IsActive = 1 AND Business.IsActive = 0)
            ) THEN 1 ELSE 0
FROM
    inserted AS t0
WHERE
    Business.Identifier = t0.IdentifierBusiness
AND
    t0.IsActive = 1
AND
    Business.IsActive = 0   

-- inserting the new rows
INSERT INTO BusinessHistory
(
    Date
    ,IsActive
    ,IdentifierBusiness
)
SELECT
    DATE()
    ,t0.IsActive
    ,t0.Identifier
FROM
    inserted AS t0

-- Forcing rowCount for EntityFramework 
DECLARE @Identifier BIGINT;
SET @Identifier = scope_identity()
SELECT @Identifier AS Identifier
```

**So, in a nutshell, what happened ?**

We have 2 tables, Business and Contact. Contact is updating table Business on insert and update.

When Business is updated, it does an insert into BusinessHistory, which is storing the history of updates of table Business
,when the field IsActive is updated.

the thing is, even if I don't insert a new row in BusinessHistory, I launch an insert instruction and so, I go inside the instead of insert trigger of the table BusinessHistory. Of course, in the end of this one, there is a scope_identity(). You can use scope_identity only once, and it gives back the last identity inserted.
 So, since I did not inserted any BusinessHistory, it was consuming the scope_identity of my newly inserted contact : the scope_identity of the instead of 
 insert of the contact table was empty !

**How to isolate the issue ?**

- Using the profiler, you figure out that there are insert instruction in BusinessHistory when it should not be any of them.
- Using the debugging, you will eventually end in the an insert trigger your are not supposed to be in.

**How to fix it ?**

Several alternatives here. What I did was to surround in table Business the insert of BusinessHistory by an If condition : 
I want the insert to be inserted only if the statut "IsActive" has changed :

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        inserted AS t0
    INNER JOIN
        deleted AS t1 ON t0.Identifier = t1.Identifier
    WHERE
        (t0.IsActive <> t1.IsActive)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BusinessHistory
    (
        Date
        ,IsActive
        ,IdentifierBusiness
    )
    SELECT
        DATE()
        ,t0.IsActive
        ,t0.Identifier
    FROM
        inserted AS t0
    INNER JOIN
        deleted AS t1 ON t0.Identifier = t1.Identifier
    WHERE   
        (t0.IsActive <> t1.IsActive)
END
```

An other possibility is, in the trigger instead of insert of the table BusinessHistory, to surround the whole trigger by an IF EXISTS condition

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
BEGIN
    ----Trigger's code here ! 
END
```

**How to avoid it ?**

- Well, use one of these fixes !
- Avoiding scope_identity(), @@IDENTITY is more than enough in most of the cases ! In my company, we only use scope_identity because of EF 4 !

I know my english is not perfect, I can edit if it's not good enough, or if someone want to add something on this subject !